# Ffmpeg speed processing time

Tags: ffmpeg

I have made this ffmpeg code but it is very slow to process. The backgroundvideo.mp4 is 4k but the final output is 960x540. Is ffmpeg processing the effects in 4k and than scale the video? Should I write the script in other order or should I downscale the video and than apply the other filters?

```
ffmpeg -t 00:00:09 -i "backgroundvideo.mp4" -i "photo.jpg" -i logo.png \
-filter_complex "[0]boxblur=20[video];[1][video]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih/1.2[photo][video];\
[video][photo]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:format=auto[bg];\
[bg][2]overlay=0:0,subtitles=subtitle.ass:force_style='WrapStyle=0,format=yuv420p" \
-i "audio.wav" -map 0:v:0 -map 3:a:0 -vcodec h264_nvenc \
-s 960x540 -shortest -r 25 -crf 17 -aspect 16/9 output.mp4
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downscale before adding more filters:

```
ffmpeg -t 00:00:09 -i "backgroundvideo.mp4" -i "photo.jpg" -i logo.png -i "audio.wav" -filter_complex "[0]scale=960:-2,boxblur=20[video];[1][video]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih/1.2[photo][vid];[vid][photo]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:format=auto[bg];[bg][2]overlay=0:0,subtitles=aegisub.ass:force_style='WrapStyle=0',format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map 3:a:0 -vcodec h264_nvenc -shortest -r 25 -crf 17 output.mp4
```